# bootstrap datetimepicker validation end date from other picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How bootstrap datetimepicker  validation end date from other picker

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="from-datepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="well">
  <div id="to-datepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () { 
$('#from-datepicker').datetimepicker({format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',pickSeconds: false,pick12HourFormat: false});
$('#to-datepicker').datetimepicker({format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',pickSeconds: false,pick12HourFormat: false});});
</script>
```

ToDate must be later FromDate. How do it?

Comment: yes but where to put this check

Comment: on the click event of whatever you use the dates for (submit button maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify check in the datetimepicker's change event.

```
$('#to-datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    //if (to>from)
       //code here
    //else 
       //code here
});
```